# Show / Hide Sections Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

#### Componet.ts

```
import .....;

export class SalesComponent implements OnInit {
    salesForm: FormGroup;

    constructor ( private formBuild: FormBuilder) {}

     ngOnInit() {
      this.salesForm = this.formBuild.group({
          type : new FormControl(),
          person : new FormControl()
      });
     }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="salesForm">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>MOBILE PHONES</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" formControlName="type" name="type" value="LG">LG</label>
      <label><input type="radio" formControlName="type" name="type" value="HTC">HTC</label>
     </div>

     <legend>PEOPLE</legend>
     <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" formControlName="person" value="JAMES">JAMES</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" formControlName="person"  value="JOHN">JOHN</label>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
   <div *ngIf=" type == 'HTC' " class="form-group">
    <h1>HTC RESULT PHONES</h1>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf=" person == 'JAMES' " class="form-group">
    <h1>JAMES RESULT</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

## Basically

- When a user selects `LG` I want to show the HTC Result Phones
- When a user selects `JAMES` I want to show JAMES Content

I am using `template driven` forms. if that makes a difference
[Please see plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview) not Working

Comment: You need to use `type.value` in your `*ngIf` instead of just `type`. Like this: `*ngIf="type.value == 'HTC'"`

Comment: @Faisal 

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SalesComponent.html:114)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14651)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get form values, now you are checking component properties.

```
<div *ngIf=" salesForm.get('type').value === 'HTC' " class="form-group">
  <h1>HTC RESULT PHONES</h1>
</div>
<div *ngIf=" salesForm.get('person').value === 'JAMES' " class="form-group">
  <h1>JAMES RESULT</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @patryk-gulas

+1

Comment: this wouldn't work for `person`, since it will set the value to `true` or `false`. Here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmho6n?file=app%2Fapp.component.html ( +1 nevertheless. )

Comment: Yes, I just saw this a couple of min ago. **`Checkboxes` do not work**.
Do you have any suggestions @patryk

In the mean time I am using radio buttons

Comment: You can create FormArray and store checkboxes values here. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqbew8

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`===`** when you are checking for string which will also check the type

```
  <div *ngIf=" type === 'HTC' " class="form-group">
```

Comment: Not Working. I tried that It does not show the `HTC RESULTS` div [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview)